# MYSQL Conditional Always Evaluating to Else

Tags: mysql, triggers, xampp, conditional-statements

The below `MYSQL` conditional from a `trigger` is always evaluating to the `ELSE` statement after I have verified the numbers are as expected.  If I make the following assumptions: `NEW.exit_time = '2019-04-09 11:50:00'`, `OLD.enter_time = '2019-04-09 11:00:00'` I expect `time_in_minutes = 50`, which should then `SET NEW.total = 25` if `plot_minimum_cost = 25`.  I have verified that the select statements populating plot_minimum_cost and plot_minute_cost are accurate given that plot_max_cost is functioning correctly and it is using the same logic to retrieve.  What am I missing?

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS get_total_parking_cost;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER get_total_parking_cost BEFORE UPDATE
ON records
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE plot_minimum_cost DOUBLE;
    DECLARE plot_max_cost DOUBLE;
    DECLARE plot_minute_cost DOUBLE;
    DECLARE time_in_lot DATETIME;
    DECLARE time_in_minutes DOUBLE;

    SELECT parking_lots.min_cost INTO plot_minimum_cost
    FROM parking_lots
    WHERE parking_lots.id = OLD.parking_id;

    SELECT parking_lots.max_cost INTO plot_max_cost
    FROM parking_lots
    WHERE parking_lots.id = OLD.parking_id;

    SELECT parking_lots.minutely_cost INTO plot_minute_cost
    FROM parking_lots
    WHERE parking_lots.id = OLD.parking_id;

    SET @time_in_lot = TIMEDIFF(NEW.exit_time, OLD.enter_time);

    SET @time_in_minutes = (HOUR(time_in_lot) * 60) + MINUTE(time_in_lot);

    IF @time_in_minutes <= 60 THEN
        SET NEW.total = plot_minimum_cost;

    ELSEIF @time_in_minutes <= 300 THEN
        SET NEW.total = time_in_minutes * plot_minute_cost;

    ELSE
        SET NEW.total = plot_max_cost;
    END IF;  

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What's with the inconsistent `@`s? Also, the various `plot_`  seem to come from nowhere; from your initial problem description, I'd guess they need OLD/NEW.

Comment: @Uueerdo typo fixing now sorry!  Didn't fix my problem though

Comment: @Uueerdo Added full trigger.

Comment: @Uueerdo Just found the below and fixed it, which solved my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared the local variable `time_in_lot` and are using it in `(HOUR(time_in_lot) * 60) + MINUTE(time_in_lot)`; but you never actually set it. You set `@time_in_lot` which is a session variable. Similarly, you are setting `@time_in_minutes` even though you've declared an `time_in_minutes`; but in that case you are using the `@` version for the IF conditions.

Basically, remove all instances of the `@` character from the trigger and see if that fixes it.